# How to remove the Full Screen mode? (InAppBrowser)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, iframe

I use Ionic 3.
My navigation bars have disappeared. I would like to see my navigation bars.
 How to remove the Full Screen mode?

```js
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser'; 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var navigator: any;
declare var Connection: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    Connection: any;
    isLaunch: Boolean = false;

    constructor( private platform: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.launch();
        });

    }

    launch() {
        this.isLaunch = true;
        const browser = this.iab.create('https://twitter.com/','_self' , "location=yes");

    browser.show();
}
}
```

```html
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to keep your navigation bar when in-app browser opens. One thing that might help would be to use themeable-browser, with which you can have buttons and a menu on the top:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser/

Comment: Please, see question about "Themeable Browser"
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375709/how-to-access-the-site-without-leaving-my-application-themeable-browser)
Thank you.